# how to convert String Array to list HashMap in java?

Tags: java, json

I Want to Convert JsonArray to List < HashMap >

```
[{"alarmCount":"192","sensorId":"CM07000071"},
{"alarmCount":"192","sensorId":"CM07000072"}]
```

### I Try this code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<CamelCaseHashMap> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<CamelCaseHashMap>>(){});
```

but try code was error

### Error

```
The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for
the arguments (String, TypeReference<List<CamelCaseHashMap>>)
```

### CamelCaseHashMap Class

```
public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        return super.put(JdbcUtils.convertUnderscoreNameToPropertyName(key), value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess jackson is used to read the json data.

Required imports:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;
```

Implementation of `CamelCaseHashMap`:

```
private static class CamelCaseHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    // add your code here...
  }
}
```

...then the following code will work as expected:

```
String json = "[{\"alarmCount\":\"192\",\"sensorId\":\"CM07000071\"},{\"alarmCount\":\"192\",\"sensorId\":\"CM07000072\"}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<CamelCaseHashMap> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<CamelCaseHashMap>>(){});
```

Comment: readValue error : The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, new TypeReference<List<CamelCaseHashMap>>(){})

I made CamelCaseHashMap class.... what am i wrong???